# Does an iterated exponential $z^{z^{z^{...}}}$ always have a finite period

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, lambert-w, chaos-theory, tetration

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}.$  Let $t = W(-\ln z)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W Function.  Define the sequence $a_n$ by $a_0 = z$ and $a_{n+1} = z^{a_n}$ for $n \geq 1$, that is to say $a_n$ is the sequence $z, z^z, z^{z^z} ...$  This is sometimes called the iterated exponential with base $z$.

Here I am trying to prove (or disprove) $2$ things:

> 1. For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is $y^\star \in [0,\infty)$ such that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|y| > y^\star$ the iterated exponential with base $z = x+ yi$ converges to a set of $3$ periodic accumulation points.  As $|y| \to \infty$ the $3$ points approach the orbit $\lbrace 0, 1, z \rbrace$
> 2. Let $E = (e^{1/e} , \infty) \cup \lbrace s \in \mathbb{C}:|t| = |W(-\ln s)| = 1 $ and $t^n \ne 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ If $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus E$, the iterated exponential is bounded and there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the iterated exponential converges to a set of $k$ periodic accumulation points.

I have been studying Daniel Geisler's tetration [map](https://www.tetration.org/); my first question is essentially a formalization of some observations I have made.  My second question has proven to be more problematic.  I have been experimenting numerically for several years, and I have observed that an iterated exponential sometimes gets "slingshot" to a neighborhood of $\infty$.  When this happens it can be very difficult to tell what the next terms will be.

The main thing I have tried in these situations is a kind of asymptotic analysis.  The next term $a_{n+1}$ is considered as the product $z^{\Re(a_n)}(z^i)^{\Im(a_n)}$.  There are $36$ possibilities determined by the signs of $\Re(a_n), \Im(a_n)$ and whether $|z|, |z^i|$ are greater than, less than, or equal to $1$.  Typically, though each factor is either $0, \infty,$ or else it just keeps going around the unit circle and doesn't approach any fixed value.  So there are really only $3$ possibilities: $0, \infty, 0\cdot\infty$.

If I'm "lucky" enough to get $a_{n+1} \sim 0$, I can easily see that the "slingshot to $\infty$" is followed by (approximately) $\lbrace 0, 1, z, z^z, \ldots \rbrace$ Otherwise I get stuck in limbo: it may be that the entire sequence is diverging to $\infty$. However, I have never been able to find specific examples of this, other than $(e^{1/e} , \infty)$.  If I get $a_{n+1}\sim \infty$ this basically puts me back at square one; I can ask the same question about $a_{n+2}$, namely, is it $0, \infty$, or something else.  So, in most (if not all) cases, I feel I have to explicitly calculate the next terms; otherwise I have no way of knowing if the whole sequence diverges to $\infty$, or if some subsequent term is very close to $0$.

Another major problem is that the next term often is so big that it causes an overflow error on my calculator.  I have tried calculating the natural logs of the terms, using the iteration $b_0 = \ln z, b_{n+1} = e^{b_n}\ln z$, but sometimes it doesn't help, because I still get overflow errors.  An example of this is $z = -2.5.$ After just 6 terms $a_n$ is on the order of $10^{26649}$ and $b_n$ has an almost identical value after 7 terms.

**Note**: all of my work so far assumes the use of the principal branches of the natural log and the Lambert W function.

Comment: Just one question: "in case 3b (...) has period k for some $k \in \mathbb N$" - do you really mean "periodic" and thus a set of *k* periodic accumulation points to which the iteration converges? Please pardon, if I'm messing some things up?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yes, that is what I mean.  I'm the one who should be apologizing, because I wasn't exactly sure how to say that, so instead I said something which apparently caused some confusion.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I would also like to point out that I am purposefully omitting case 3b from consideration, because in my opinion it is the most "troublesome" of the 4 cases.

Comment: you didn't talk so much of the different branches of $\log(z)$ and $W(z)$, and how changing of branch of $\log$ during the iteration $a_{n+1} = z^{a_n} = e^{a_n \log(z)}$ affects the result. and how do you prove $3a$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 First, I am assuming that any work done on this is made using the principal branch of the natural log.  This is because, as far as I can tell, the orbits produced by the principal log are the most studied and most well understood.  Also, the other branches of $W(z)$ appear to have no relationship to the iterated exponential.  When defining $a_n$ using different branches of the log, I have found there are 2 different ways to do this, which lead to completely different results.

Comment: @user1952009 Second, I would never intentionally change branches of log during an iteration.  In my opinion, the resulting orbit would be practically meaningless.

Comment: @user1952009 Third, this came up in my previous post.  YiannisGalidakis has told me this is proved by "Baker and Rippon."  Yiannis did state the relevant theorem of Baker / Rippon, but they did not give any details of the proof, and I have not been able to find the relevant articles.

Comment: Hmm, I've looked at bases $z$ in case 3b where the *arg()* of the associated $t$ is not an algebraic fraction of the unit circle but a transcendental with a high transcendental degree, like Liouville's number or $c=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-2^k}$ (see my question yesterday) , which have arbitrary well approximations to a rational number. According to the convergents of the continued fraction the basic rough periodicity of *3*, *4*, *5* or more step until roughly a "round" is closed iterating with number-of-steps from the continued fraction convergents ...

Comment: ... give *arbitrary small* stepwidths, and the curve (with fractal border) gets more and more dense. But because the starting point $a(0)=z$ we have also $a(-1)=1$ and $a(-2)=0$. Now because we can do arbitrarily small steps by selecting a high stepwiths $w$ we can approach $a(-2+w)$ near zero arbitrarily near. Of course $a(-2+w)$has a precedessor, $a(-3+w)$ which must then be arbitrarily distant from the origin, which is then *an argument* (no proof yet) for the "slingshot to infinity". With algebraic $c$ I think this is not principally different, only the approximation to zero is slower.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms That is very interesting, but my goal with this question isn't so much finding conditions for a "slingshot to infinity" to occur, as it is proving or disproving the statements in block quotes.  Though I suppose it is relevant since the "slingshot to infinity" has caused significant complications in my numerical investigations.  I hope you expand your comments into a detailed answer.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Any chance you could expand your recent comments into some sort of answer?  They sound very interesting and I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @cpiegore - give me a little time.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Are you still intending to post an answer to this question?

Comment: cpiegore: I've put my experiments,pictures and thoughts together in one pdf. Unfortunately - as I had mentioned earlier - it does not discuss your real question about the periodicity in general and the $y*$- question in particular. From the beginning I was misunderstanding the focus of your question and while you *exclude* the region $E$ I thought just that were of interest. But because you seem much interested in spite of my misinterpretations here is the link: http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/_equator/mse160614_equator.pdf Hope you'll have fun...

Comment: Just updated a bit my essay linked to in the comment before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt at proving statement 1.  Showing that the conclusion holds for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|y| > y^\star$ basically boils down to proving $\lim\limits_{|y| \to \infty}(x+yi)^{x+yi} = 0$ for fixed $x$.  Without loss of generality we may assume $y >0$ since $\bar z^{\bar z} = \overline{z^z}$.  We may also ignore the argument of $(x+yi)^{x+yi}$ and show that $|(x+yi)^{x+yi}| \to 0$

$|(x+yi)^{x+yi}| = (x^2+y^2)^{x/2}e^{y\arctan(x/y)-y\pi/2}$.  Since $x$ is fixed $(x^2+y^2)^{x/2} \sim y^{x}$ and since $y\arctan(x/y) \to x$, as $y \to \infty$ we have $e^{y\arctan(x/y)-y\pi/2} \sim e^{-y} \implies (x+yi)^{x+yi} \sim y^{x}e^{-y} \to 0$ since $e^{-y} \to 0$ way faster than $y^{x} \to \infty$.

I am still not sure how to show there is a smallest value $y^\star$ for which the conclusion is true.  Nor do I know of a formula, or even an algorithm, to find it, other than a lot of numerical experimentation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(x^2+y^2)^{x/2} \sim y^{\color{red}{x}}$?

Comment: No because $x$ is fixed, ie, $x$ is a constant with respect to $y$, ie, I am only taking the limit with respect to $y$

Comment: Okay, I admit I am not perfect.  I may have misunderstood the use of the tilde symbol.

Comment: Actually it should be $(x^2+y^2)^{x/2} \sim y^{x/2}$, but the limit is still $0$ since $e^y$ grows faster than **any** power of $y$

Comment: Why $x/2$? As far as I can tell, $(y^2)^{x/2} = y^x$. Am I missing something? But of course the limit is still $0$ that way.

Comment: No you were right the first time.

Comment: On a more interesting note, do you have any idea how to find $y^\star$

Comment: Unfortunately not.